# How to import SQLite database in Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, database-connection

I am creating an Android Application and I recently downloaded a SQLite Database Browser. I have created a database which has 3 tables. Now I'm wondering on how to import the created database into Eclpise IDE.

I hope someone could help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your `SQLiteDatabase` file inside the `assets` folder of your project.

Comment: Is there a need for me to import the database in the eclipse?

Comment: @kyle: Yes, like I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Open the *DDMS* perspective in Eclipse. There you should have a tab saying *File Explorer* (remember to select your emulator device in the *Devices* tab). You can use this to browse to your database file on the emulator. The database should be located in \data\data\[name_of_your_app]\databases. You can then select the database file (.db) and copy it to a local folder (there is a *Pull a file from the device* button in the upper right corner of this tab).

Also note that this is only possible on an emulator, since you're not allowed to browse the content on a real device this way.

Comment: Thank you! I'll follow the instructions and let you know if it works. Thanks again..